# What is purpose of setting a 'temp' variable in this problem?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I was working on a Java problem (pasted below), and the answer key (picture link included at the bottom) used a variable named 'temp'. Why is it necessary to include a temp?

The following program segment is a method that should accept a two-dimensional String array "image" and flip the "image" 180 degrees vertically. For example:

1 2 3 4 --4 3 2 1

1 2 3 4 -> 4 3 2 1

1 2 3 4 -- 4 3 2 1

answer key:

[image: answer key]

Comment: Classical swap. Google "how to swap two variables"

Comment: Please add relevant code in your question.

Comment: You can even swap them without using that temp variable, its a typical way to swap two entities.

Answer (score 1):

This is standard swap technique. To swap value of two variables, we use a third variable temp to temporarily store the value of first variable and so that when it's value gets overridden, it doesn't get lost. Then finally we use the temp to store value in the second variable.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common way of swapping the values of two variables. If one were to write `a = b; b = a;`, then variable `a` would point to the same value of `b`, but the pointer to the value `a` originally referred to would effectively be lost. Therefore, it's necessary to store the value inside a temporary value, hence `temp`.